# Can you think of a synonym for "female banker"? Or can the feminine ending be used somehow?

Tags: single-word-requests

Marie Medici, from the Medici clan in Milan, married the King of France Henri VI.

The King's mistress, Henriette d'Estragues, hated the Queen's guts.

She dubbed her "*une grosse banquière*", which means "fat banker," except *banquière* in French is feminine, whereas "banker" in English is either masculine or neutral.

Can you think of a synonym or an equivalent phrase in English that would indicate that it was a woman that Henriette was trying to insult? "Bankeress" sounds ridiculous. Or not. I don't know.

[Marie di' Medici](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Frans_Pourbus%2C_the_Younger_-_Marie_de_M%C3%A9dicis_-_1920.1034_-_Art_Institute_of_Chicago.jpg)

Comment: Is there some compelling reason that requires calling out that our lady banker here is female?  I presume we've already met her by now, and so already know that. If not, then I might not worry much about skipping this incidental, possibly purely grammatical, element from your translation. Certainly better that than digging up some awkward or mothmalled word for this, such as *bankeress* or *bankerette*, let alone *bankster* or *banxter* — or *lady banker*. :)

Comment: @tchrist: Believe it or not: yes. Certain words used as insults just don't work when applied to the opposite gender. "He's a dragon." Huh? "She's a douche." Huh? They're gender-specific. Calling a man a banker doesn't even sound like an insult. In this particular case, "moneybags," which is gender-neutral, would in fact work better than "banker." The problem is, the lady in question DID come from a family of bankers, and not incorporating that in the translation would be historically inaccurate. Am I making any sense?

Comment: Of course, English _did_ use expressions like 'poetess', 'authoress', even 'doctoress', implying that it was unusual for a woman to do those jobs. At the time such words were current, it would have been pretty unthinkable for a woman to have a senior post in a bank, but I think 'bankeress' may still be your best bet.

Comment: @KateBunting: Sappho, who was "The Poetess" just like Homer was "The Poet," would take umbrage. Seriously, though, I think you're right. Antiquated or not, that's what Henriette called her.

Comment: The title of the 1980 french film "La banquière" (starring Romy Schneider) was translated as **the lady banker** (*as proposed by @tchrist*).

Comment: @Graffito: Yes, but that wasn't derisive.

Comment: I'm surprised to see how many [written instances of ***brokeress***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22brokeress%22) there are. But my dumb-ass spell-checker still thinks it has to be underlined!

Comment: @Ricky While calling a man a banker wouldn't sound like an insult in English, calling a woman a banker wouldn't either.

Comment: I'm sure if you try hard you can find a gendered term for "fat" which you can attach to "banker". Or an adjectival form of "banker" you can attach to a term for a fat woman. This would be outside the scope of ELU SE, happily.

Comment: In the US the *ess* ending has been falling out of use because of changing social attitudes; even during the second half of the 20th century use of the *ess* ending was rather limited to certain roles and occupations: Actress. Hostess. Seamstress.  Years ago, I lived in England for a while, and was surprised to hear how the *ess* ending was used more broadly there. The term "manageress" seemed freakish to me.

Comment: @TimR We still have lionesses and tigresses.

Comment: @tchrist and temptresses and seductresses and mistresses, too :-) But I was thinking of occupational and social-role names. We have nothing like manageress and brokeress.

Comment: @TimR The [paywalled OED lists 649 compounds and words derived from *‑ess*](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/ess_suffix1?tab=etymology#compounds_and_derived_words), many more than just   *actress* and *countess* and *princess* and *priestess* and *giantess* and *goddess* and *sorceress*. :) You can read a summary list of these [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64763116#64763116) if you'd like.

Comment: @tchrist: that list does not reflect AmE currency.  Most of them have no currency whatsoever.

Comment: @TimR Prithee, where did our esteemed asker include such piddling constraints above future contestants? Does this story take place in the New World? I think not!

Comment: Ah, I thought I was talking to the evil but sensible twin of @tchrist  who offered this sage advice: "Certainly better that than digging up some awkward or moth[b]alled word"

Answer (score 2):

*Bankeress* is indeed a word. From the *OED*:

> **bankeress** *noun*
>
> **2.** A female banker. Now *rare*.
>
> <sub>**1883**   The late Countess of Jersey was only received on
> sufferance in some houses in Vienna, because she was a bankeress.
> —*American* vol. 5 200</sub>
>
> <sub>**2009**   Why would it be any better to have dozens of
> female management consultants, bankeresses, social workers and
> lawyers, clutching briefcases? —*Mail on Sunday* (Nexis) 25
> October)</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Comment: Lovely! Thanks for confirming.